# SQL referring to same table in a query Stuck

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that requires me to join/refers to the same table, however, I am unable to get a result using the query.

Below is a sample of my query

```
SELECT a."column1", b."column1" as anotherColumn
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
where a.'x' = b.'x' 
AND NOT a.'y' = b.'y'
```

This query take forever to load. However, if I just run:

```
SELECT a."column1"
FROM table1 AS A
```

it only takes 14sec.

I'm currently using PostgreSQL with Pgadmin. table1 has 1.4million table currently.

Is it because there is a lock on the table 1 when it was first referred to as a?

EDIT : Each row contains the record of "author","book published" and in this case, there might be many authors for a book hence being collaborators. What I am trying to achieve is to find out the number of collaborators for each author

Comment: The first query does not join the two tables. You are creating a cartesian product (aka "cross join") between those two tables. Why?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have edited my question, hope it clarifies what I am trying to achieve. Thanks for the letting me know it was actually doing a cross join

Comment: @fukanchik I added the WHERE clause which I think you meant by my subquery? I added it more details to my question hoping it will clarify some points. Is there a way to produce the "collaborators" result without such joins?

Comment: create index on table1(x);
create index on table2(x);

Comment: and don't forget create index on table1(y); create index on table2(y);

Comment: you use pgadmin?.. give us reproducible table structure

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to achieve is to find out the number of collaborators for each author

Something like this would count the number of authors, and I guess where that number is greater than 1, the number of collaborators is that number - 1

```
select b.name, count(a.*)-1 as num_collaborators
from books b
inner join authors a on b.id = a.book_id
group by b.name
having count(a.*) > 1
```

---

```
--original
SELECT a."column1", b."column1" as anotherColumn
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
;

--amended
SELECT a."column1", b."column1" as anotherColumn
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
where a.'x' = b.'x' 
AND NOT a.'y' = b.'y'
```

**Over 25 years ago** ANSI standards for SQL introduced a more "explicit" syntax for joins and using this is well established as "best practice" now.

One of the greatest benefits of this "explicit join syntax" is that accidentally forgetting to join properly becomes impossible, unlike the original query which did forget the joining predicate. (& When that happens an unexpected Cartesian product is produced.)

So, I encourage you to **stop using commas between table names**. Taking that simple step will help you use better join syntax.